# How to receive/send file, data on .net(C#) Sockets and distinguish them

Tags: c#, .net, file, sockets, asynchronous

I have async Server and async Client on .net Sockets.
Client creates object(for example class UserInfo), serializes him, and writes in byte[].
Also Client has some file(1.png for example).
Client need to sent serialized UserInfo and 1.png to the server.

I use for file,

> Socket.BeginSendFile Method (String, AsyncCallback, Object)

and for byte[] object

> client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
>                   new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);

Server must receive this date together and understand what is file and what is serizalize object(because server has only one method for receive data).

```
listener.BeginAccept(
new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
listener);
...
AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{...
 handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
}
```

and our logic in

```
ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {...}
```

How to receive this data correctly? In finally i need that server has 1.png and UserInfo object.(and distinguish them). Moreover, because the server is asynchronous, it should not be confused when receiving data from multiple clients simultaneously

i have one idea, but i think this is wrong:
Try to use  on a client

> Socket.BeginSendFile Method (String, Byte[], Byte[], TransmitFileOptions, AsyncCallback, Object)

with byte[] preBuffer, where i will write header, such this "..."
and on server i try to find this header, cut it, analyse and do some activity.

Is there a way easier and more correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each channel (socket) should have definite and known protocol, in terms of implementation - well known type of objects. So introduce a main class which will encapsulate all data which could be sent via this socket:

```
public interface IPacketWrapper
{
   IEnumerable<byte> Payload { get; }
   UserInfo UserDetails { get; }
}
```

So client and server exchange by objects which implements `IPacketWrapper` so you can put together both binary data and `UserInfo`, then serialize/deserialize this object on client/server side respectively.